# If $Y$ and $Z$ are subspaces of a vector space $X$, show that $Y\cap Z$ is a subspace of $X$, but $Y\cup Z$ need not be one. Give examples.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functional-analysis, proof-verification

**If $Y$ and $Z$ are subspaces of a vector space $X$, show that $Y\cap Z$ is a
subspace of $X$, but $Y\cup Z$ need not be one. Give examples.**

Both $Y, Z$ are subspaces of $X$, which tells us that $0 ∈ Y$ and $0 ∈ Z$, which means $0 ∈ Y ∩ Z$. If $u, w ∈ Y ∩ Z$, then by definition $u, w ∈ Y$ and $u, w ∈ Z$. Since $Y,Z$ are subspaces, they are closed under addition - meaning $u + w ∈ Y$ and $u + w ∈ Z$, implying $u + w ∈ Y ∩ Z$. Any single element $u ∈ Y ∩ Z$ is in $Y$ and in $Z$, so that $cu ∈ Y$ and $cu ∈ Z$ for any scalar $c$, meaning
of course that $cu ∈ Y ∩ Z$. Thus the intersection $Y ∩ Z$ is a subspace of $X$.

For a counterexample, let $Y = \{(x,0): x ∈ \mathbb{R}\}$ and $Z = \{(0,y): y ∈ \mathbb{R}\}$. Then $u =(1,0) ∈ Y ⊂Y ∪ Z$,  $w =(0,1)∈ Z ⊂ Y ∪ Z$ But $u + w =(1,1)\notin Y \text{ or } Z ⇒ (u + w)\notin Y ∪ Z$.

Comment: Looks perfect to me, mathematically. You could have some more air around your text, though, with line breaks and paragraphs to make it easier to read.

Comment: To me as well, well done.